# Match strings from main df with those in reference df - if found, add all cols from that row of the reference df into main df

Tags: r, string, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a "main_df" along the lines of this:

```
structure(list(study_id = c("02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", 
"02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz"
), question = c("3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL", "b8GLxGjZKtstCQZ", "40iyFKjeMEFGI2V", 
"6eZGejSZ1oTZYLb", "3pXAUvZH8GGuryd", "0kYkUAHe4iODUl7"), study_rt = c("1.353", 
"0.714", "0.68", "0.695", "0.696", "0.656"), study_response = c("picture", 
"picture", "picture", "picture", "picture", "picture")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), reshapeWide = list(
v.names = NULL, timevar = "index", idvar = c("study_id", 
"question"), times = c("rt", "response"), varying = structure(c("response.rt", 
"response.response"), .Dim = 1:2)), groups = structure(list(
study_id = "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", .rows = list(1:6)), row.names = c(NA,
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

and a reference df along the lines of this:

```
structure(list(stim = c("ashtray_word", "bell_word", "blouse_word", 
"boot_word", "bottle_word", "bread_word"), url = c("eW1BRoUDV4BKQMl", 
"5zKTGwHlwlzpssB", "55SVfoQudZJNCFT", "bOORR1zuKYSnAe9", "6RrOQfDZim81pHv", 
"1F97ouH0HrwQOgZ"), study_list = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Each value in the 'question' column of the main df can be found in the 'url' column of the reference df. I want to match these values, and add all columns from that row of the reference df to my main df. The output will look like this:

```
structure(list(study_id = c("02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", 
"02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", "02ipnnqgeovkrxz"
), question = c("3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL", "b8GLxGjZKtstCQZ", "40iyFKjeMEFGI2V", 
"6eZGejSZ1oTZYLb", "3pXAUvZH8GGuryd", "0kYkUAHe4iODUl7"), study_rt = c("1.353", 
"0.714", "0.68", "0.695", "0.696", "0.656"), study_response = c("picture", 
"picture", "picture", "picture", "picture", "picture"), stim = c("chisel_picture",
"raccoon_picture", "apple_picture", "belt_picture", "bicycle_picture", 
"cake_picture"), url = c("3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL", "b8GLxGjZKtstCQZ", 
"40iyFKjeMEFGI2V", "6eZGejSZ1oTZYLb", "3pXAUvZH8GGuryd", "0kYkUAHe4iODUl7"
), study_list = c("B FILLER", "B FILLER", "B", "B", "B", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(study_id = "02ipnnqgeovkrxz", .rows = list(
1:6)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This will allow me to see the 'sensible' item names (e.g. "chisel_picture") that subjects were responding to, as opposed to the nonsensical code names I have now (e.g. "3eEVJgaAP6c9FPL"). The same items appear over and over again in the 'question' column (as different subjects saw the same items), and I need to preserve these repeats.

I have successfully managed this using a for loop...but it's super slow! A tidyverse solution would be amazing!

My awful for loop (study_data = main df / image_urls = reference df):

```
    all_study_stim_items <- study_data$question   # List all values in 'question' column.
    matched_items <- tibble()                     # Create empty tibble to store results of for loop. 

    for (i in all_study_stim_items) {
       temp <- image_urls %>%
       filter(url == i) %>%
       select(stim, url, study_list)
    matched_items <- bind_rows(matched_items, temp) }   # Continuously overwrite tibble with each match.

# I then join this with the main df.
```

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match. But I guess, you need `merge(df, df2, by.x="question", by.y="url")` perhaps with an `all`-argument, depending on your actual task.

Comment: Yup. So simple, I was clearly overthinking it wayyyy too much. Many thanks :)